# How to remove the header and the section header of the theme Berkeley ONLY from title page (optionally also in table of content) on Beamer?

Tags: beamer, themes

### What I used :

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usetheme{Berkeley}
```

### What is my problem :

In the titlepage slide I also have the **header** and the **aside**, I would like to have them **everywhere except on the title** (and also no side on the table of content if possible).

```
    \begin{frame}
        \titlepage
    \end{frame}
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Table of Contents}
        \tableofcontents
    \end{frame}
```

### What I tried (and why it's not fitting) :

```
    \begin{frame}[plain]
        \titlepage
    \end{frame}
    \begin{frame}[plain]
        \frametitle{Table of Contents}
        \tableofcontents
    \end{frame}
```

this is actually **removing the header and aside but** :

- then the slide content is **not centered anymore**
- for **table of content** I would like to keep the header and **remove only the "section header"** in the aside
- \logo is also removed and I wished to keep it (optional)

### Minimal code to copy paste to reproduce :

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usetheme{Berkeley}

\title[the title]
{blablabla}

\subtitle{Olala}

\author[name] 
{
    name surname
}

\institute[rand] 
{
  Faculty of something\\
  Somewhere University
}

\date[2020] 
{Something, 2020}

\logo{\includegraphics[height=1.5cm]{picture.png}} %for reproduce put a random picture.png in your folder

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
        \titlepage
    \end{frame}
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Table of Contents}
        \tableofcontents
    \end{frame}

    \section{nSection}

    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{a slide title}
        lorem ipsum
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

### Remark:

If this question is easy I am sorry I am new to beamer and LaTeX in general

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SX! As a new member, it is recommended to visit the [Welcome](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) and the [Tour](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tour) pages to be informed about our format and also to know about [Minimal Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228).

Comment: Thank you @R.N, I read those post and I make a small edit, can you point me out if there is still something wrong ? Thank you in advance :)

Comment: an easy but ugly solution could be to use `[plain]` and `\vspace` `\hspace` to center manually the title page.